# I can't add a new list item in Bootstrap tab

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the following code for creating a tabbed interface:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Chart 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Chart 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Chart 3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

As soon as I add,

```
 <li>Chart 4</li>
```

before the `</ul>`, the CHart 4 text appears as simple text, with no tab boundary. Why is this happening?

Comment: Its working fine, You didnt added <a> tag for tab4.. try with that it will work fine   <li><a href="#">Chart 3</a></li>

Comment: It would be a simple text as the Tab needs a `<a>` tag around it also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because Bootstrap 3 tabs were having styles for `<a>`, without `<a>` it doesn't match the conditions to get the tab navigation styling. Here is the sample Bootstrap 3 CSS code for Tabs:

```
.nav-tabs > li > a {
  margin-right: 2px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a:hover {
  border-color: #eeeeee #eeeeee #dddddd;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #555555;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

Try like this [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7102/):

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Chart 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Chart 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Chart 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Chart 4</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Sounds like stupid but this is the correct answer cause CSS declared it has to be with an `<a>` tag to work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But what if I don't need the <a> bit? I will put an onclick listener that will hide divs based on which tab is pressed. Why should I use <a> then?

Comment: Then you have to customize your tab, where in bootstrap they wrote style with <a> only, so edit it / create your own css according to your requirement